# How to coerce pandas dataframe column to be normal index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create a `DataFrame` from a dictionary. I want the keys to be used as index and the values as a single column. This is what I managed to do so far:

```
import pandas as pd
my_counts = {"A": 43, "B": 42}
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_counts, name=("count",)).rename_axis("letter"))
```

I get the following:

```
       count
letter      
A         43
B         42
```

The problem is I want to concatenate (with `pd.concat`) this with other dataframes, that have the same index name (`letter`), and seemingly the same single column (`count`), but I end up with an
`AssertionError: invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype`.

I discovered that the other dataframes have a different type for their columns: `Index(['count'], dtype='object')`. The above dataframe has     `MultiIndex(levels=[['count']], labels=[[0]])`.

**How can I ensure my dataframe has a normal index?**

Comment: Are you producing the MultiIndex using the Dataframe constructor as you're showing? I can't reproduce the Index this way.

Comment: Yes. And this could be version-dependent. I noticed the problem with a script that used to work a few months ago...

Comment: I'm thinking it is. Are you able to set `df.index = df.index.get_level_values(0)` without any ill effects?

Comment: I can, but this doesn't seem to change the MultiIndex nature of `df.columns`

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed- try `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)`. Zipping levels together when flattening an actual MultiIndex works this way, so I'm hoping this will work.

Comment: @AndrewL This seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the multiIndex column with this code by eliminating a ',':

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_counts, name=("count")).rename_axis("letter"))

df.columns
```

Output:

```
Index(['count'], dtype='object')
```

OR you can flatten your multiindex columns like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_counts, name=("count",)).rename_axis("letter"))

df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)

df.columns
```

Output:

```
Index(['count'], dtype='object')
```